# Equivalence classes of Wilson lines in $SU(2)_k$ Chern-Simons theory

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

One basic aspect of the 3D TQFT/2D CFT correspondence that I'd like to understand better is the following.  It is often said that the ground states of Chern-Simons theory on a (spatial) torus are in one-to-one correspondence with the distinct Wilson lines of the theory.  This can be seen in canonical quantization, as per Witten's original paper.  It is natural to ask what "distinct" means, namely: what are the precise equivalence classes of Wilson lines that map to these ground states?

The answer to this question in the case of abelian Chern-Simons seems to be well-known (see, e.g., Appendix C of [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04251) recent paper).  I am interested in the case of simple gauge group $G$; for simplicity, let me phrase the question in the context of $SU(2)$.  $SU(2)_k$ Chern-Simons on a torus has $k + 1$ ground states labeled by half-integers $j = 0, \ldots, k/2$.  These can equivalently be viewed as the $k + 1$ primary operators in the $SU(2)_k$ WZW model, where the truncation of $SU(2)$ representations to the set of integrable representations of the $SU(2)_k$ affine Kac-Moody algebra is well-understood.  From the 3D point of view, however, a Wilson line can carry any $SU(2)$ representation (half-integer $j$): to respect the 2D truncation, all such lines should fall into equivalence classes labeled by the basic lines $j = 0, \ldots, k/2$.  To help identify these equivalence classes, it is natural to examine the correlation functions of these lines (rather, loops).  Recall that the modular $S$-matrix of $SU(2)_k$ is given by
$$
S_{jj'} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{k + 2}}\sin\left[\frac{\pi(2j + 1)(2j' + 1)}{k + 2}\right],
$$
in a basis of integrable representations.  Two basic observables of $SU(2)_k$ Chern-Simons on $S^3$ are the expectation value of an unknotted spin-$j$ Wilson loop and the expectation value of two Wilson loops of spins $j, j'$ in a Hopf link, which I denote by
$$
\langle W_j\rangle = \frac{S_{0j}}{S_{00}}, \quad \langle W_j W_{j'}\rangle = \frac{S_{jj'}}{S_{00}},
$$
respectively.  One sees that the first (positive) value of $j$ for which $\langle W_j\rangle = 0$ is that immediately above the truncation threshold: $j = (k + 1)/2$.  More generally, from these expressions, it is clear that a line of spin $j$ and a line of spin $j + k + 2$ have identical correlation functions, while lines with $j = n(k/2 + 1) - 1/2$ for any integer $n$ do not exist (vanish identically).  Here, one should distinguish the *trivial* line $j = 0$, which has $\langle W_0\rangle = 1$ and trivial braiding with all other lines, from *nonexistent* lines, which have $\langle W_j\rangle = 0$ and vanishing correlation functions with all other lines.  On the other hand, a line with $j$ and a line with $j + k/2 + 1$ have the same expectation value and braiding, *up to a sign*.  In other words, at the level of correlation functions, $SU(2)_k$ Wilson lines are antiperiodic with period $k/2 + 1$.

The **question**, then, is as follows: although a spin-$j$ line and a spin-$(j + k/2 + 1)$ line can be distinguished in 3D by their correlation functions, do they map to the same states in 2D CFT (as one would naively expect), and if so, how can one see this?

If one is ambitious, one could try to explain the analogue of this antiperiodicity phenomenon for arbitrary simple, compact $G$.  Here, once more, the 2D side seems well-understood (in contrast to the 3D side): for instance, in an arbitrary WZW model, the fusion rule eigenvalues (computed from the $S$-matrix elements) are equal to the finite Weyl characters of $G$, evaluated on some special Cartan angles that respect the truncation of the relevant representations ([Verlinde](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321388906037?via%3Dihub)).